# different width of same text across browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

The width of text is rendered differently across Chrome(/safari), FF and IE. There is a quite big difference between Chrome and FF, while only small gaps between FF and IE. You can see the difference by opening this in browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/xhx9z/

Does anybody know if there is any way to reduce the gap so that the width are close across browsers.

Simple test:

```
<span>this is a test of text width and see the difference across browsers<span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('span').width());
});
```

The results of width are:

```
chrome/safari: 501
FF: 519
IE: 520
```

Comment: "It's worse than you think": *MY* Safari reports 520.

Comment: :), it is. Chrome and Safari has same core engine, so should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need these elements to be a certain size, don't let the browser compute it: force what you need it to be using CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't fix the width, the content of text is dynamic.

Comment: you can force the size of the bounding box. There is no way, whatsoever to force the size of an individual letter, or spacing between letters/words. Not even between browsers it is different, but also between OS's (chrome windows renders different then chrome linux ie.).

Answer (score 0):

Rendering text depend from Operating system settings, used browser.
And always will be different.
Try another way to solve the preceding problem.